# How do i exit a loop running in threadA after I get a specified input in threadB? in java

Tags: java, multithreading

```
import java.io.*;

public class ThreadSanbox {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                StopThread stX = new StopThread();
                boolean runLoopX = true;
                while (runLoopX) {
                    System.out.println("runLoopX val: "+runLoopX);
                    runLoopX = stX.getRunLoop();                    
                }
                System.out.println("runLoopX val: "+ runLoopX);
            }
        });
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                BufferedReader userInput = new BufferedReader(
                              new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                String userInputStr = "";
                StopThread st = new StopThread();
                int count = 0;
                do {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Enter a value:");
                        userInputStr = userInput.readLine().trim();
                        System.out.println("User Input: " + userInputStr);
                        count++;
                    } catch (Exception e) {System.err.println(e.toString());}
                } while (userInputStr.equals("e") == false);        
                st.setRunLoop(false);
            }
        });
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        try {
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
        } catch (Exception e) {System.err.println(e.toString());}
    }
}

class StopThread
{
    private boolean runLoop = true;
    public synchronized boolean getRunLoop() {return runLoop;}
    public synchronized void setRunLoop(boolean val) {runLoop = val;}         
}
```

In the above code I want to run threads t1 and t2.  In t2 i want to get input from the keyboard and if the input is e i want to exit the do while and set the value of runLoop to false so that the while loop in t1 also exits.  How do I do this?

Comment: Give us a clue here - what currently happens when you run the code?

Comment: Instead of creating two different `StopThread`s, try create one instance at the beginning (from the main thread) and pass it to `t1` and `t2`. You also need to make if final. So: `final StopThread st = new StopThread();` right under the `main` header

Comment: don't we need to make the runLoop variable volatile so that we always get the latest???

Comment: @Navin not in this case, because it is the same thread updating and reading the variable

Comment: @TheNail i can see t1 and t2 (if using the same object st of StopThread as per your suggestion) trying to access here though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your two threads have two separate instances of `StopThread`. You need them to share a single instance so that they can communicate.

One way to do this is to create subclasses of Thread or Runnable so that you can pass the shared StopThread instance into each of them in their constructors.

Another way is to make a simple variable in the enclosing class (both threads will be able to 'see' this variable so they can use it to communicate).

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to pass messages between t1 and t2, or to be more specific: From t2 to t1. Either you let t2 know t1 and implement a method for stopping or you use some external common state. I guess the latter is what the `StopThread` class is thought for. But then you need *one* instance that is shared between the two threads.

Answer (score 0):

**You should probably implement a form of [message passing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_passing).** For example:

A shared resource that both threads can read and write to

```
static AtomicBoolean stopLoop = new AtomicBoolean(); // defaults to false
```

.. in the keyboard listener thread ..

```
stopLoop.set(true);
```

.. and in the waiting thread ..

```
while( stopLoop.get() == false ) { /*wait, consider Thread.sleep()-ing*/ }
```

The idea is that there's **ONE** shared, thread-safe resource that both tasks use to communicate. In your case it doesn't have to be atomic because only one thread writes, but its good practice. It should **NOT** be a thread instance variable. Reference [AtomicBoolean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html).

Comment: @shresthaal glad I could help. you could reinforce that with a +1 ;)

Answer (score 0):

Having a special variable to stop your Runnables is not a bad idea, but it is specific to your classes, so it's not a "general purpose" way to do things.  A more general purpose way you should consider would be to check whether the Thread is interrupted.  Many threading frameworks, such as Java.util.concurrent, use interrupts to tell running tasks to stop.

So, instead of loops or tests on the boolean runLoop, you'd check `Thread.interrupted()`.  And to tell the Thread to stop, call `theThread.interrupt();`

Another big advantage is that this will handle many (but, alas, not all) cases where the task is waiting, sleeping, or waiting on I/O.

Answer (score -3):

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29 ,
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupted%28%29 ,
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isInterrupted%28%29 and
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/InterruptedException.html